# Knuth Morris Pratt Algorithm, keep getting error "control reaches end of non-void function"

Tags: c

Code keeps returning the error "control reaches end of non-void function".

The source of the error is probably: `int lps[M]` but I can't figure out how to fix it. I tried to assign value to it but the error is still there.

EDIT: sorry about the return -1; thing. Fixed that but the error I'm trying to fix is still there.

```c
int knuth(char *string, char * pattern){

    int M = strlen(string);
    int N = strlen(pattern);

    int lps[M];

    if (string == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while (i < N) {
            if (string[j] == pattern[i]) {
                j++;
                i++;
            }

            if (j == M) {
                //printf("Found stringtern at index %d ", i - j);
                j = lps[j - 1];
                return i - j;
            } else if (i < N && string[j] != pattern[i]) {
                if (j != 0)
                    j = lps[j - 1];
                else
                    i = i + 1;
            }
            return i - j;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `return -1;` is inside `if`, move it outside, just before last `}`

Comment: you function may reach a case where it returns nothing, make sure you `return` something before the last `}`

Comment: What happens if `string` _is_ null?

Comment: If you use proper brace placement and formatting, you might discover where some compound statements start and where they end...

Comment: The compiler tells you at which line the warnign occurs. What is unclear about that?

Comment: @Lundin: On checking the raw only the final closing brace was misplaced, and that by one or two spaces. It appears rather that OP doesn't know markdown yet. Thus I would say to OP, check the edit to learn markdown.

Comment: if(string != NULL) -- has no return on the `else` branch.

Comment: @Joshua Both the function brace, the outer if and the while statement are all messed up.

Comment: I dont see the `lps[]` array ever being assigned to. Its contents are basically random.

Comment: Ok the new edit made the whole code formatting even more of a mess. Hint: copy/paste the original source code as-is, then hit the brace icon for source code formatting. [Backtick][Backtick][Backtick]c also works.

Comment: there's no point to this `while` loop, the function will unconditionally `return` if at the end of the first iteration of the loop. But what does it `return` if the loop is never entered? That's what the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: What do you return if `patten` is an empty string?

Comment: Your `return i - j;` statement is inside the loop.  If the loop exits, you drop out of the function without returning a value.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring all other potential problems in this function, the compiler is rightfully complaining that not all code paths `return` a value.  You have declared the `knuth` function to return an `int`, yet it's possible for logic in your function to reach the end *without* `return`ing a value.  If you go down one of those paths, the function will return an indeterminate value, and if the caller uses that value, it will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  See the condensed version of your function below:

```c
int knuth(char *string, char * pattern){
    if (string == NULL)
    {
        return -1;  // ok, here's a return, but it's conditional on string == NULL
    }
    else {
        while (...) {

            if (...) {
                return i - j;  // here's another return, also conditional
            } else if (...) {

            }
            return i - j; // here's the final return in your function, which is
                          // conditional on entering the while loop
        }
        // what if you get here (ie, the condition of the while loop was false)?
        // The function returns nothing, this is what the compiler is warning
        // you about.
    }
    // Here is logically the same as at the end of the else block .. also no return
}
```

As I mentioned in my comment, there's no point to the `while` loop, since you *unconditionally* `return` from it at the end of the first iteration.  That means the loop is guaranteed to only execute once, eliminating the need for a loop all together.  Your logic can be simplified, at least with a method as below:

```c
int knuth(char *string, char * pattern){
    int i=0, j=0;

    if (string == NULL)
    {
        return -1;  // ok, here's a return, but it's conditional on string == NULL
    }
    else if (i < N) {
        // if i < N, do whatever manipulations you want as before
        if (...) {
            // return i - j;  // really no need to return i-j here, we'll do that
                              // at the end now
        } else if (...) {

        }
    }
    // now at the very end of the function, this will unconditionally return
    return i - j;
}
```

However, I suspect you actually want to loop, in which case your logic should be something like

```c
int knuth(char *string, char * pattern){
    int i=0, j=0;
    if (string == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        while (i < N)
        {
            // ... do your operations. Be _very_ careful to increment
            // i appropriately (probably each time thru the loop), otherwise
            // you'll get an infinite loop here. I see a conditional
            // mutation of i in your OP, which makes me nervous.
        }
        // since this is the end of an else block, we can return here
        //return i - j;
    }
    // but IMO it's clearer to return here. It's up to you, depending on
    // where you want to scope i and j
    return i - j;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code falls off the end of the function when `string == NULL`.

This writing style is old; typically we would not write

```
 if(string != NULL)
    {
      /* Entire body logic */
    }
```

but rather we would now write

```
 if(string == NULL)
    {
        /* handle input error and return; or do we do string = ""; */
    }
```

You will find this mistake more easily avoided by using the modern style. It has been pointed out to me that `string` can't be `NULL` here because of the `strlen(string)` call above. While such a platform does exist where `strlen()` checks for `NULL`, depending on that behavior is unwise, and the check should be moved before the `strlen(string)` call.

Nobody believes in single return anymore, which was the only real reason for the old style.

Comment: it also crashes before that, because of strlen

Comment: @user253751: Depends. At least one platform returns 0 if a `NULL` is passed to `strlen`.

Comment: The correct solution is to outsource the NULL check to the caller, through documentation. It has nothing to do with the purpose of the function so it shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Lundin: That's a philosophy debate that OP is not ready for. Depending on what you're working on it can go the other way.

Comment: No it can _never_ be the task of some Knuth algorithm to sanitize application-level pointers. Such code should be located as close to the point where the pointers are suspected to go haywire as possible.

Comment: @Joshua — any string function that doesn't abort (or crash) when passed a NULL pointer is an abomination.  And I include `printf()` in that category.  Strictlym ==, it is undefined behaviour, but defining it as 'harmless' is a very bad idea.